# Remove item at given position in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

My users can delete items in my `Navigation Drawer`, they select which one they wish to delete and it **should** be removed from the menu.

Here is how I try to do it so far:

```
// Should remove item at position 'which'
private void removeTab(int which) {
    NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    Menu menu = navView.getMenu();

    menu.removeItem(which + 1);
}
```

But it does not remove the item.

I'm not sure this is how `removeItem` should work, is there a way to remove an item in a `Navigation Drawer` using its position in the menu?

EDIT:

I get the idea of hiding the item, but that is problematic as I will have to keep track of the number of items hidden in order to hide the next one. (If Item1 and Item2 are hidden then Item3 is still at position 3 and not 1 when displayed).

Comment: You can use change visibility.

Comment: But that does not make much sense if my user permanently deletes the item.

Comment: Are you sure we can delete the menu item ?? I think you should store the values of visibility in database and act accordingly

Comment: That would not be logical for a ToDoList application where my users can add and remove lists daily. I'm not sure of anything, I'm asking if there is a way to do it

Comment: Then you can design your own NavigationDrawer, i think this will be the easiest way to develop such functionalities if you cannot remove the items

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NavigationView navigationView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
hideItem();


 }

private void hideItem()
{
 navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
 nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_settings).setVisible(false);


 }
```

Comment: you can hide menu via this line  nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_settings).setVisible(false);

Answer (score 0):

You can hold the data in an arraylist. When you swipe over an item, you can remove the item from the array list `arraylist.remove(index)` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

**Important:**

If you implement this solution, you have to pass the arraylist to the adapter and work on the same list object.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide the id of `MenuItem` to be removed inside `removeItem`. not position.

like this:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                navigationView.getMenu().removeItem(item.getItemId());
            }
        });
```